# Pytorch. How I can expand dimension in tensor (from [[1, 2, 3]] to [[1, 2, 3, 4]])?

Tags: torch, tensor

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
print(x)
# some operatons?
print(x)
```

Out:

```
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3]])
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

I tried tensor.expand() method, but nor success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution...

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> print(x)
>>> print(x.size())

tensor([[1, 2, 3]])
torch.Size([1, 3])

>>> x = x.repeat_interleave(torch.tensor([1, 1, 2]))
>>> print(x)
>>> print(x.size())

tensor([1, 2, 3, 3])
torch.Size([4])

>>> x[3] = 4
>>> x = x.unsqueeze(0)
>>> print(x)
>>> print(x.size())

tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
torch.Size([1, 4])
```